# Is there anything wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-question, asking-questions

This is my first question on SO: [Change document flow on page break to fill space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787490/change-document-flow-on-page-break-to-fill-space). It's here for a week now and has received only small attention and one downvote. Is there something I can do to improve the question?

I have taken decent time to search for answer by myself, and to explain it the best I could. I've also read tons of "how to ask properly on SO"-related stuff before posting the question and double-checked all tags to be appropriate.

Voter didn't leave any comment and I can't see anything in question that deserved downvoting, so I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: Some people use downvotes and NARQ close votes to mean "I don't know". Have an upvote, even though it probably doesn't imply that I know.

Comment: Don't worry about a single vote, up or down. For all you know it's someone voting without even reading the question, in a run for [Electorate](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate).

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! Sorry you had a less-than-stellar experience with your first question, because personally I feel it was well-asked, just possibly a little obscure :/

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am aware that asking if something is possible but not (yet) necessarily usable might seem a little "obscure". I'm doing pre-research for my master's thesis, thus I'm focused on technical feasibility based on specifications more than on momentary usability in browsers, which is not critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem with your question.

It may be a topic not very understood by a large group of users, but help will arrive.

You need to realize that certain questions, depending on the time of the day that you've posted them, may leave the **interesting** tab fast enough (*front page*), thus losing the users attention.

If it is a problem to each you haven't been able to solve yet, you can **edit your question** to alter some contents or trying to rephrase it, that will bump it to the front page.

In the future, with more reputation, you can even **start a bounty**, to catch the users interest, thus collecting the answers you seek.